# Inactive browser cache when logout take place

Tags: java, jsp

How to disable browser cache when logout takes place. I used:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> <!-- tells browser not to cache -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> <!-- says that the cache expires 'now' -->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> <!-- says not to use cached stuff, if there is any -->
```

But still I am getting the previous page , when I click logout.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The previous page'.  I suppose logout goes to 'Next page'.

Comment: Consider i login and navigating so many pages , when i logout , i should allow to access or view the previous from my navigation . i should show the login page when i click back button .

Comment: Did you put the cache control tags on all the pages?  If not your previous page might be in cache giving this problem.

Comment: yes i put above cache control in all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on most browsers, but to prevent Firefox from caching, you need an additional two headers `Cache-Control=no-store` and `Cache-Control=must-revalidate`. Therefore try:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate">
```

See [how can i prevent firefox caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467451/how-can-i-prevent-firefox-caching).